# EntryComponents in Module for LazyLoading

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to load a modal from a component. In Angular Material documentation is write to add the modal component in entryComponents :

This :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AidesRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [TypesAidesComponent, TypesAidesAjouterComponent],
  entryComponents : [TypesAidesAjouterComponent]
})
export class AidesModule {

}
```

In TypesAidesComponent I want open dialog with TypesAidesAjouterComponent :

```
let dialog = this.dialog.open(TypesAidesAjouterComponent);
    dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
      if(res){
        this.collection.addItem(res);
      }
    });
```

I'm in a component lazyloading :

```
{
        path: 'types-aides',
        loadChildren: 'app/modules/aides/aides.module#AidesModule'
    },
```

But I have this error :

**Error: No component factory found for TypesAidesAjouterComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?**

I have found a solution, it is to move remove the LazyLoading but my application is large and is not a possibility.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common complaint with Angular at the moment. In certain instances, extracting a small component out of a lazy loaded module is not possible because of how dependency injection works. **Components have to be brought into the application through their respective Module, which means if the module hasn't been loaded, you can't use any of the Components it declares.**

I had to come to terms with the fact that there really are very few instances where this need arises in a well structured application, and that bumping up against it should be a sign that I needed to re-evaluate the structure of the application.

The best way to get around this issue is to extract the component and either create a separate module for it, or add it to a shared module that is imported into the module you are rendering it within.

Comment: In fact, that's exactly what I had to do. It does not suit me but I will do with: /

Comment: any alternative solution for this?

Comment: So, essentially, any components you want to load dynamically can't be in a lazy loaded module, and have to be imported at the app level. Is that correct? Seems like a vast oversight, especially if you have components that may be both instantiated dynamically and statically...Could you add some more detail to how you think that you could better structure your application to avoid this issue?

Comment: I don't think the problem has something to do with bad structure. You just have modals in a lazy module. They should not be loaded, unless the module is loaded.

Comment: I have added the lazy loaded module to my project but have to add the component name into entryCompoents because Angular throws an exception i.e. No Factory found error for component. But after adding into entrycompoents fix it.   But Does the component is actually lazy loaded after adding into entrycomponent. ?

Answer (score 3):

An **alternative** would be to use **TemplateRef**. This is especially useful in the case of the Angular Material dialog example above, which support both ComponentType and TemplateRef.

In the HTML, you can use @Input to pass your data to the component

```
<ng-template #popup>
  <my-component [data]="data"></my-component>
</ng-template>
```

The TS is very simple and there is no need to worry about the module to be lazy loaded or to use entryComponent.

```
@ViewChild("popup") popupRef: TemplateRef<any>;

public handleClick() {
  this.modalService.open(this.popupRef, options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's very useful answer.
This works NgbModal too.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same or a very similar issue with `Angular Bootstrap` and a modal popup. Our first finding was, that if we import the lazy loaded module into our app-moule the popup worked.
In the end, we had to

*... add NgbModule to the imports of the @NgModule decorator of the module the popup was a part of,*

although we have NgbModule already imported in the app-module and no import was missed by the compiler in the ts file of the popup component.

I hope this can help someone. Please be kind.

Comment: works for me thx - although importing NgbModalModule works too and wont import the whole lib

Comment: I can also confirm this is the correct answer for Angular Bootstrap (NgBootstrap)

Answer (score 2):

So unfortunately this probably won't help you with the Angular Material dialog, but for anyone else running into the same issue with dynamically generated components in general, after running into the same issue when using my custom Modal component, and I developed an alternative solution: Passing the `ComponentFactoryResolver` I use in my custom modal service from the component that calls it.

So for example, let's say I have 2 components in a lazy loaded module: `ModalContentComponent` and `CallerComponent`.

In my `CallerComponent`, my constructor looks like this:

```
  constructor(
    private modalService: ModalService,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ) {}
```

And I call my modal service with:

```
this.modalService.open(ModalContentComponent, this.resolver);
```

And inside of my ModalService, if the resolver is provided in the open function, I use this passed resolver instead of the injected normally into my ModalService. This allows me to selectively provide my lazy loaded module's context as needed without having to restructure my entire application.

Comment: Maybe you can also provide the `ModalService` so we know what do the `open` function was actually doing.

Comment: Can you provide "modalService" class ?