# Angular Lazy Loading Modules and entryComponents error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, lazy-loading

I'm lazy loading an angular module and while trying to open my `DatesModal` I'm getting this error:

```
No component factory found for DatesModal. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

My `lazyModule` looks like this:

`declarations: [DatesModal]
entryComponents: [DatesModal]`

Im definitely adding the `DatesModal` in the entryComponents array of the lazyModule. Anyone got any idea what I could be missing here?

Please let me know if you need more info to answer this question.

Comment: Try restarting the dev server, if you haven't already

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EntryComponents in Module for LazyLoading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48908746/entrycomponents-in-module-for-lazyloading)

Comment: I have tried that as well, could it be related to angular injector in anyway, since lazy loaded module creates a new injector?

Comment: This is on the assumption that you are trying to show the modal after the module that declares it has been loaded?

Comment: if you are using `DatesModal` component in another module then make sure you export it  `exports: [ DatesModal ]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to get/import this module in other modules, however this module is not visible to others. Try to export your module:

```
exports: [DatesModal]
```

UPDATE:

[As  Angular docs says:](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components#the-entrycomponents-array)

> For production apps you want to load the smallest code possible. The
>   code should contain only the classes that you actually need and
>   exclude components that are never used. For this reason, the Angular
>   compiler only generates code for components which are reachable from
>   the entryComponents; This means that adding more references to
>   @NgModule.declarations does not imply that they will necessarily be
>   included in the final bundle.
>   If a component isn't an entry component and isn't found in a template,
>   the tree shaker will throw it away. So, it's best to add only the
>   components that are truly entry components to help keep your app as
>   trim as possible.

To make your module to be lzay loaded, you need to do in routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(mod => mod.CustomersModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(mod => mod.OrdersModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

[Read this docs about how to make your modules to be lazy loaded.](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: Hi, just to clarify you're suggesting I try and export the lazy loaded module correct? Also thanks for the answer.

Comment: I was wondering whether this could be an issue due to angular injector in anyway, since lazy loaded module creates a new injector? What do you think?

Comment: @Skywalker I am just wondering whether you've solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any third-party library (or yourself) to dynamic create this component in lazy-load module?

If so, you need to add this component in the AppModule's (or up-level non-lazy-load module) `entrycomponents`.

More detail you can see this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324)